# Unable to install npm via cmd in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-package

I'm trying to install npm via command prompt in Windows but it's not working. Following is the list of commands I've run for this purpose.

```
C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity-practice-2>node -v
v15.14.0

C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity-practice-2>npm -v
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity-practice-2>npm install -g npm
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity-practice-2>node install -g npm
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity-practice-2\install'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: How did you install node.js?

Comment: @gretal Read the question again, the results of these attempts are already shown.

Comment: @Fuaad Reinstall node.js. It seems your npm is missing.

Comment: Isn't there any way to install npm separately?